# creation of 2D double array from a text file

Tags: c, arrays

I want to write a program to create a 2D double array from a text file. The contents and format of my file is

```
0,0.23645,8.457
4.125,7.102,8.102
1.036,0.547,3.2298,
```

Same number of row and same number of column. Each number is differentiated by one ','. Each line is differentiated by one'\n' character and at the end one comma.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
  FILE *myfile
  float a,data[10][10];
  char ch;
  int i,j;
  clrscr();
  myfile=fopen("E:\\input.txt", "r");
   for(i = 0; i<3; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0 ; j<3; j++)
    {
      fscanf(myfile,"%f %c",&a,&ch);
      printf("%f ",a);
      data[i][j]=a;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  fclose(myfile);
  printf("\n");
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  { for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {   printf("%f ",data[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  getch();
}
```

It is working, but not for every time. Sometimes it is giving garbage values, zeros or NAN. I don't know why the result of same code gives sometimes correct or sometimes wrong values?

In this code, I have made my number of row/column constant. But if it is unknown then how do I do? So, I have written another code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
  FILE *myfile;
  float a,data[10][10];
  char ch;
  int i,j,line=0,target=0;
  int f=getc(myfile);
   clrscr();
  myfile=fopen("E:\\input.txt", "r");
  while (f!= EOF)
  { if(f=='\n')
    line++;
    f=getc(myfile);
  }
  //printf("%d",line);
  target=++line;
  //printf("%d",target);
  for(i = 0; i<target; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0 ; j<target; j++)
    {
      fscanf(myfile,"%f %c",&a,&ch);
      printf("%f ",a);
      data[i][j]=a;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  fclose(myfile);
  printf("\n");
  for(i=0;i<target;i++)
  { for(j=0;j<target;j++)
    {   printf("%f ",data[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  getch();
}
```

But it is not at all working, everytime is giving wrong values.

Kindly help

Comment: `getc(input)` accesses `input` uninitialized.

Comment: If you're sure there are 4 floats per line, use `fscanf(input, "%f,%f,%f,%f", &f1, &f2, &f3, &f4);`. Here `fN` could also be replaced with your array elements directly.

Comment: @meaning-matters use `%lf` for `double`. and _one'\n' character and at the end one comma_

Comment: @BLUEPIXY True, thanks for correction.

Comment: @meaning matters this is not working properly, it is removing the first character

Comment: how to remove the comma? without comma it is fine

Answer (score 0):

It's done with the following code.

`#include <stdio.h>`
`#include<conio.h>`
`void main()`
`{`
`FILE *myfile;`
`float a,data[10][10];`
`char ch;`
`int i=0,j=0,target=-1;`
`clrscr();`
`myfile=fopen("E:\\input.txt", "r");`
`while(1)`
`{`
`while(1)`
`{ fscanf(myfile,"%f %c",&a,&ch);`
`data[i][j]=a;`
`j++;`
`if(ch=='0')`
`{ target=j;`
`break;`
`}`
`else if(j==target)`
`break;`
`}`
`j=0;`
`i++;`
`if(i==target)`
`break;`
`}`
`fclose(myfile);`
`for(i=0;i<target;i++)`
`{    for(j=0;j<target;j++)`
`{   printf("%f ",data[i][j]);`
`}`
`printf("\n");`
`}`
`getch();`
`}`

removed the EOF, rather using while loop.